# Error : SpecFlow designer codebehind generation is not compatible with MSBuild codebehind generation

Tags: visual-studio-2019, specflow

I am using visual studio 2019 in mac to setup my test automation framework in c# & Specflow  . When i build my test automation framework in VS i am getting below error :

> SpecFlow designer codebehind generation is not compatible with MSBuild codebehind generation. The custom tool must be removed from the file

On searching through forums, people recommending to remove the custom tool selected as "SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator". But when i check the same in VS 2019 for Mac it is not enabled for me to remove.

attaching the screenshotn. Can anyone help me with this issue ?

[image: pecf]

Comment: Which version of SpecFlow are you using?

Comment: Did you see my answer to your question? Have a look in the Visual Studio SpecFlow preferences. I posted a screenshot of Visual Studio 2019 for Windows, which might be similar. It might help to post a screenshot of the SpecFlow preferences for VS 2019 Mac. The screenshot you currently show is not the preferences for SpecFlow, but the **properties** of one of the feature files.

Answer (score 1):

double click on "AutomationTests" or right click edit your AutomationTests.csproj file
search for SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator
and remove it manually

Comment: Yes, this answer helped me! 
You need to 
1. Right-click on your project called "AutomationTests"
2. Click on "Edit Project File"
3. Find all occurrences `<Generator>SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator</Generator>` in the file and comment/delete them out

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not familiar with Visual Studio for Mac, but presumably the settings are the same or similar to Windows.*

---

Check the SpecFlow options in Visual Studio. Make sure **Enable SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator CustomTool** is set to **False**. If Visual Studio for Mac is anything like windows, go to Tools > Options > SpecFlow, then look under the **Legacy** section.

A screenshot from Windows is below, showing the setting in question:

[image: Screenshot of the options window in VS 2019 for Windows showing the legacy setting.]

Comment: It looks like you also have to blank out the SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator field against each feature file: https://specflow.org/blog/changes-to-the-specflow-visual-studio-extension/

Comment: @SteveSmith Thank you! that worked for me.